# Failure moving a file on the server via html file form

Tags: php, html, json

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this.

I have the client select a json file from his local file system and then have some server code copy it in a folder on the server. Doesn't work.

The form:

```
<form name="jsonFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="tmp.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
  <h2>Json File</h2>
    <input type='file' id='fileinput' >
    <input type='button' name = 'jsonf' value='Load'>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

The server code:

```
<?php
 if ($_FILES['jsonf']['error'] > 0)
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES['jsonf']['error'] . "<br>";
 else {
 $savepath = "Users/";
 $filename = basename($_FILES['jsonf']['tmp_name']);
 $saveto   = $savepath . $filename.'.json';

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['jsonf']['tmp_name'], $saveto))
  print_r($_FILES);
 else
  print_r($_FILES);

 echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['jsonf']['name'] . "<br>";
 echo "Type: " . $_FILES['jsonf']['type'] . "<br>";
 echo "Size: " . ($_FILES['jsonf']['size'] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
 echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES['jsonf']['tmp_name'];
 }
 ?>
```

I know about all the security problems and plan on doing some checking and validation in the process but I can't get the file on the server to begin with so I have to make that work first.

The problem is I have a similar form for some image file and it does work.

Comment: where? No. The page just stays the same. I've tried different things, moving the name around, changing the path, using different combinations of forms etc. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an HTML problem. You need to correct the button type to submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="jsonf" value="Load">
```